# Remove component from page source when visible is set to false

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a situation when I want a primefaces' dialog to be displayed only under some conditions so what I made is to set visible attribute. Now I wonder, is it possible to hide component in rendered html when visible is set to false? Let's say someone wiser will work with my application and he will decide to display page's source code and there he will notice my hidden dialog and then he will remove my 'visible' attribute. What happens is that dialog will be displayed to him although it shouldn't be shown. Of course I can write my methods in such way that even if he display the dialog he will not be able to do anything wrong but I would prefer to remove my dialog from rendered html. Is it possible?

Comment: Even if the dialog were to be removed in its entirely from the rendered HTML, it would not be hard/tricky to add that dialog (even though the code that generates the dialog is absent in the generated/rendered HTML). Anyone can easily play such tricks. Therefore, you should only rely upon this, "*I can write my methods in such way that even if he display the dialog he will not be able to do anything wrong*" as you already stated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `rendered` attribute and set it to `false`.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="enclosing-panel">
   <p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40" rendered="#{somecController.dialogRendered}">
     <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
   </p:dialog>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Whenever you need the dialog use ajax to refresh a div(`<h:panelGroup/>`) enclosing the dialog.

```
<p:commandButton value="show dialog" type="button" oncomplete="PF('dlg1').show();" actionListener="#{somecController.refreshPanel}" update="enclosing-panel" />
```

Comment: So you recommend to write it in the way where I have both rendered and visible attributes and rendered is always set to false? Maybe I should inform that if my dialog is displayed it is displayed while page is loaded. I click button which redirects me to another page and when the second page is loaded then dialog is displayed in the same moment. This is why i give up rendered attribute.

Comment: @wawek , you dont need visible attribute in this case. you use a code similar to what i have given in <p:commandButton/> to show and hide the div. I have not tested the code.

Comment: Ok i think I got your point but here is simple example when after clicking a button dialog is displayed. I got more complex example where dialog is displayed after page is loaded so where should I put 'oncomplete' attribute and how should I implement actionListener? BTW I heard that I can achieve my example by packing my dialog into ui:component (I think) but I cannot find example in the web and I kinda do not understand how can I accomplish that.

Comment: @wawek, so you do it the other way around. Use `window.onload` to display dialog. Then when you close the dialog set rendered to false.

Comment: Well now I wonder what happens when I would have both rendered and visible attributes set to the same value? I cannot test it now but won't it be displayed when condition evaluates to true and hidden + not rendered in html when condition equals false?

Comment: @wawek, when components are rendered if the components rendered attribute is set to false, then it is just ignored. So setting the display to false is useless. But surely you can do this.